# Cannot mount netatalk volume

Tags: macos, mount, afp

I'm setting up a centos Server with usage of netatalk.
Installation showed no error, afp.conf seems to be ok, service is running:

```
 netatalk.service - Netatalk AFP fileserver for Macintosh clients
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netatalk.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-09 18:22:23 CEST; 21h ago
     ...
  Process: 32631 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netatalk (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 32630 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/netatalk.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 32634 (netatalk)
    Tasks: 4
   Memory: 3.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/netatalk.service
           ├─32634 /usr/sbin/netatalk
           ├─32635 /usr/sbin/afpd -d -F /etc/netatalk/afp.conf
           └─32636 /usr/sbin/cnid_metad -d -F /etc/netatalk/afp.conf
```

When I try to mount the volume specified in the afp.conf on a mac client, I get the error:

```
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error -1069
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: I don't know Centos at all, but wouldn't it be easier to just use SMB? Macs don't use AFP by default any more.

Comment: smb for macs on a big network was always and still is a pain the a.. And the fact that apple turns to smb does'nt make it any better ....